# Dereference Models from many to many relationship

Tags: python, google-app-engine, many-to-many, dereference, app-engine-ndb

In my schema, as described in the below test data generation example, I want to know a good way to:

Dereference all instances of Favourites that have reference keys to instances of Pictures that have been deleted. Just delete any Favourite that links to a deleted picture.

- The `Person` class is a user
- The `Picture` class is something that can be a Favourite
- The `Favourite` class is an example of the Link-Model way of having many-to-many relationships.

**Why this question?**
First I hope it doesn't fall out of the scope here, second because this can happen and third because it's interesting.

**How?**
Let's say that a person can have up to thousands favourites, something like Likes are on social networks or to make it worse, orders, accounts or invalid data in a scientific application. 
In our example for some reason (and these reasons happen) a person is experiencing lot of dead favourite link, or I do know, that there are dead favourites.

What would be a good way to do this, **reducing** `ndb.get()` operations and **not iterating** through every Favourite.

Lets not complicate things. Lets make the assumption that we have **only one user** suffering from dead favourites. He has a class of Person and stubbed user_id property of '123'.

In the following example you can use the following handlers and their corresponding functions.

```
import time
import sys
import logging
import random
import cgi
import webapp2

from google.appengine.ext import ndb


class Person(ndb.Expando):
    pass

class Picture(ndb.Expando):
    pass

class Favourite(ndb.Expando):
    user_id = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    #picture = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Picture, required=True)
    pass

class GenerateDataHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        try:
            number_of_models = abs(int(cgi.escape(self.request.get('n'))))
        except:
            number_of_models = 10
            logging.info("GET ?n=parameter not defined. Using default.")
            pass
        user_id = '123' #stub
        person = Person.query().filter(ndb.GenericProperty('user_id') == user_id).get()
        if not person:
            person  = Person()
            person.user_id = user_id #Stub
            person.put()
            logging.info("Created Person instance")
        if not self._gen_data(person, number_of_models):
            return
        self.response.write("Data generated successfully")

    def _gen_data(self, person, number_of_models):
        first, last = Picture.allocate_ids(number_of_models)
        picture_keys = [ndb.Key(Picture, id) for id in range(first, last+1)]
        pictures = [] 
        favourites = []
        for picture_key in picture_keys:
            picture = Picture(key=picture_key)
            pictures.append(picture)
            favourite = Favourite(parent=person.key,
                            user_id=person.user_id, 
                            picture=picture_key
                        )
            favourites.append(favourite)
        entities = favourites
        entities[1:1] = pictures
        ndb.put_multi(entities)
        return True

class CorruptDataHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        if not self._corrupt_data(0.5):#50% corruption
            return
        self.response.write("Data corruption completed successfully")

    def _corrupt_data(self, n):
        picture_keys = Picture.query().fetch(99999, keys_only=True)
        random_picture_keys = random.sample(picture_keys, int(float(len(picture_keys))*n))
        ndb.delete_multi(random_picture_keys)
        return True

class FixDataHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        user_id = '123' #stub
        person = Person.query().filter(ndb.GenericProperty('user_id') == user_id).get()
        self._dereference(person)

    def _dereference(self, person):
    #Here if where you implement your answer
```

Separate handlers due to eventual consistency in 
the NDB Datastore. More info: 
[GAE put_multi() entities using backend NDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205763/gae-put-multi-entities-using-backend-ndb/14215569#14215569)

Of course I am posting an answer as well to show that I tried something before posting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ReferenceProperty is just a key, so if you have the key of the deleted Person, you can use that to query the Favourite.

Otherwise, there's no easy way.  You'll have to filter through all Favourites and find ones that have an invalid Picture.  It's very simple in a mapreduce job, but could be an expensive query if you have a lot of Favourites.

Comment: Yes if Favourites are a small non costly number iterating is the optimal maybe way. But what if you have 50000 Favourites and 99999 Pictures?

Comment: You'll have to filter through 50000 favorites.  For each Favorite, check the picture, if it's invalid, delete the Favorite.  Yes, this ends up costing up to 100K entity fetches.  That's not that expensive if this is a rare (say once a month or less) cleanup operation.  You should be cleaning up the Favorites when you delete Person and Picture entities anyways, so you shouldn't need to rely on this sweep and clean.

Comment: If you're looking for a cheaper way to do this... it doesn't exist (other than the preventative method).  The best you can do is check for 'dead' Favorites when they're already being accessed (like a user is loading the page anyways), and clean it up then.  Then you might not have to make an extra effort to read entities just for the purpose of cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a pre delete hook (look [here](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/Pre--and-post--put-hooks-for-Datastore-models) for a way to implement it)
Of course this could be done easier if you use the NDB API instead of the Datastore API ([hooks on NDB](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model__pre_delete_hook)), but then you'll have to change the way you make the referenes

Comment: Thanks Nizz ;-) . I'll test and report.

Comment: Well yes it helps only to prevent the faulty links. What if the corruption is already there.....

Comment: I can't think of an inexpensive way to do this. That's why it's better to prevent a situation like this... The only thing that could work (if you don't mind hanging on to the corrupted data until you can see their result) is handling the error upon appearance i.e. a try/except statement where you will have the load part in the try block and the fix in the except block.

Comment: Well I do think there is. Like if you only use keys and don't iterate with get's  but try to implement joins.

Comment: I agree that the best is it be detected upon user action and add it to a task-queue or repair it immediately.