# GAE put_multi() entities using backend NDB

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I am using a backend to write multiple entities with `ndb.put_multi(list_of_entities)`.

The issue that I am experiencing is that just after that if I make a query then I get no results. If I put a sleep timer for eg 1 sec, I can read the entities that I just wrote.

So eg:

```
class Picture(ndb.Expando):
    pass

class Favourite(ndb.Expando):
    user_id = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    pass

#...make lists with Picture and Favourite kinds
entities = favourites
entities[1:1] = pictures
ndb.put_multi(entities)

favourites = Favourite.query().filter(Favourite.user_id == user_id).fetch(99999, keys_only=True)
logging.info(len(favourites)) #returns 0 in dev_appserver why?
```

First assumed the problem has to do with caching. **But**:

Reading [NDB Entities Operations on Multiple Keys or Entities](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#multiple):

> Advanced note: These methods interact correctly with the context and
>   caching; they don't correspond directly to specific RPC calls.

Reading [NDB Caching](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache)

> The In-Context Cache
>
> The in-context cache persists only for the duration of a single
>   incoming HTTP request and is "visible" only to the code that handles
>   that request. It's fast; this cache lives in memory. When an NDB
>   function writes to the Datastore, it also writes to the in-context
>   cache. When an NDB function reads an entity, it checks the in-context
>   cache first. If the entity is found there, no Datastore interaction
>   takes place.
>
> Queries do not look up values in any cache. However, query results are
>   written back to the in-context cache if the cache policy says so (but
>   never to Memcache).

Hm I am lost here. Everything seems to be ok. Even if query from the console I get the correct sum, but never on the same handler, no matter what function etc.

Only thing I noticed is that when put a wait `time.sleep(1)` then I get the correct results. So that has to do with the fact that the `ndb.put_multi` might not complete synchronously or not. So confused....

Comment: Suspect it's this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367904/write-read-with-high-replication-datastore-ndb/12368444 eventual consistency.

Comment: Yes I was also suspecting this @PaulC but then I have it wrong in my mind. If the `put_multi()` returns doesnt that mean that the entities have been put and the indexes and the commit was successful? I am not using the async methods.

Comment: If you are not using an ancestor query or getting the entities by keys, you run into the eventual consistency issue. If you are using an ancestor query or a key to get individual entities, then it's probably something else.

Comment: Guido keeps reminding me that the ndb cache only caches entities that you get by key/id.  Queries are not cached.  You're definitely running into an eventual consistency issue since you're not using transactions.

Comment: And your commit is successful.  That means the results will eventually show up in a query.

Comment: Thank you. I am looking into this.

Comment: @Sologoub No not using ancestor query, and that solved my issue. 
That explained a lot. Thank you all.

Comment: So if someone wants to post an nice answer about ancestor queries and eventual consistency to close this question you are welcome.

Comment: it's OK for you to answer and accept your own question too :)

Comment: Google App Engine's High Replication Datastore (HRD) provides high availability for your reads and writes by storing data synchronously in multiple data centers. However, the delay from the time a write is committed until it becomes visible in all data centers means that queries across multiple entity groups (non-ancestor queries) can only guarantee eventually consistent results. Consequently, the results of such queries may sometimes fail to reflect recent changes to the underlying data. However, a direct fetch of an entity by its key is always consistent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A clear mind in the morning is always better than a dizzy mind at night.

Thank you all for the comments. Problem solved. You lead me in the right way so to answer my question:

I used ancestor queries to get the results correctly. It's worth to mention the following

[Understanding NDB Writes: Commit, Invalidate Cache, and Apply](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/overview)

> The NDB function that writes the data (for example, put()) returns
>   after the cache invalidation; the **Apply phase happens asynchronously**.

That means that after each put the apply phase might not have completed.

And:

> This behavior affects how and when data is visible to your
>   application. The change may not be completely applied to the
>   underlying Datastore a few hundred milliseconds or so after the NDB
>   function returns. A non-ancestor query performed while a change is
>   being applied may see an inconsistent state (i.e., part but not all of
>   the change). For more information about the timing of writes and
>   queries, see Transaction Isolation in App Engine.

Also some things about consistency between read and writes taken from [Google Academy Retrieving data from the Datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/training/py101_2/lesson2)

> Google App Engine's High Replication Datastore (HRD) provides high
>   availability for your reads and writes by storing data synchronously
>   in multiple data centers. However, the delay from the time a write is
>   committed until it becomes visible in all data centers means that
>   queries across multiple entity groups (non-ancestor queries) can only
>   guarantee eventually consistent results. Consequently, the results of
>   such queries may sometimes fail to reflect recent changes to the
>   underlying data. **However, a direct fetch of an entity by its key is
>   always consistent**.

Thanks to @Paul C for constantly helping and @dragonx and @sologoub for helping me understand.